# Why there is no class like ParameterizedThreadStart<T>?

Tags: c#, multithreading, generics

The class `ParameterizedThreadStart`, always takes object as parameter. Which I suppose was introduced in .Net 1.0/1.1

But after generics was introduced, I am expecting a class like `ParameterizedThreadStart<T>`, which is still not there?

Was it missed? or
Is there any other reason?

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't really need it when you have anonymous functions.

Comment: @sVick: I tend to agree that the necessity for a `ParameterizedThreadStart<T>` is reduced by the availability of anonymous functions. However, without the class, there is an inconsistent feel about using `ParameterizedThreadStart` as it is.

Answer (score 7):

The easy workaround is to use lambdas/anonymous functions to capture local variables and then use the unparameterized threadstart.

```
ThreadStart start = () => func(param1, param2)
```

Comment: There can be workarounds.. so that we dont even need ParameterizedThreadStart.

Comment: IMO the main use for `ParameterizedThreadStart` are 1) Projects using old C# versions 2) Projects using a language that doesn't offer variable capture. I wouldn't use it in modern C# at all.